# How does app like heard works?

Tags: ios, multitasking, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I want to make app which continuously records voice in background. App like heard does exactly that.
But I am stuck on interruptions. The app fail to resume recording when it faces interruptions.

I have used this for notification :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleAudioSessionInterruption:)
                                             name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

and to resume recording I have:

```
- (void)handleAudioSessionInterruption:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSNumber *interruptionType = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];
    NSNumber *interruptionOption = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey];

    switch (interruptionType.unsignedIntegerValue) {
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan:{
            // • Audio has stopped, already inactive
            // • Change state of UI, etc., to reflect non-playing state
            NSLog(@"Audio has stopped, already inactive");

            NSLog(@"is recording: %@",recorder.isRecording?@"yes":@"no");

            [self.recorder pause];

            NSLog(@"is recording after pause: %@",recorder.isRecording?@"yes":@"no");

            //[recorder pause];

        } break;
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded:{
            // • Make session active
            // • Update user interface
            // • AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume option




            if (interruptionOption.unsignedIntegerValue == AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume) {
                // Here you should continue playback.


                //NSLog(@"completed");

                NSLog(@"start recording again %d");

                //NSLog(@"completed: %d",[recorder record]);

                // Set the audio file



                [self.recorder record];


                NSLog(@"is recording after again : %@",recorder.isRecording?@"yes":@"no");




                //[player play];
            }
        } break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in the plist the UIBackgroundModes an  'audio' as Item 0. Hope it will help - at least it works for me when playing audio.

[image]